# Public, protected and private attributes accessibility

Tags: attributes, private, public, protected

I have a question about the accessibility of the different access level of class attributes.

I wrote this code:

```
class struct:
    def __init__(self, dict):
        for key in dict:
            setattr(self, '__'+key, dict[key])
        for key in dict:
            setattr(self, '_'+key, dict[key])
        for key in dict:
            setattr(self, key, dict[key])

    def access_data(self):
        print(self.a)

    def access_protected_data(self):
        print(self._a)
 
    def access_private_data(self):
        print(self.__a)


mydict = {'a': 2, 'b': 'abc', 'c': [4]}

q = struct(mydict)
q.a = 4
q.access_data()
q._a = 5
q.access_protected_data()
q.__a = 6
q.access_private_data()
```

The program will print:

```
4
5
```

and sets `q.__a = 6`
 
I don't understand this behaviour. I would think that the program wouldn't be able to set the q.__a=6 outside of the class, at the same time I would expect the program to be able to print q.__a from a function inside the class.

Could you please explain?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-in-python-public-private-and-protected/ I think that this will help you.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, the behavior I see it's different from your example. Might it be due to how I create the private and protected attributes?